# Django don't translate several words in template

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

I have this template:

```
{% if apartment.property.type == 'condo' %}{% trans 'Apartments' %}{% endif %}
{% trans 'Square' %}
```

django.po:

```
#: templates/main/tags/special.html:11 templates/main/tags/special.html:28
#, fuzzy
msgid "Apartments"
msgstr "Квартира"

#: templates/main/tags/special.html:44
msgid "Square"
msgstr "Площадь"
```

I do "makemessages", then "compilemessages" command. Then I restart server.
BUT: When I open site in browser, i see:

```
 Apartments
 Площадь
```

So, 1 word translated and 1 not translated. More info: word "Apartments" don't translated anywhere on all site. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The string is marked as fuzzy and thus not included by Gettext in compiled translations (which are generated by `compilemessages`). The strings is usually marked as fuzzy once there was some change in original string, but there might be other reasons as well.

Comment: Ok, but why this string don't translated?

Comment: I have tried to move out word "Apartments" from "if" just now, then makemessages (without fuzzy), compilemessages. But result is the same: "Apartments" don't translated on site.

Comment: I removed "#, fuzzy" from .po files and it helps me. But I don't understand why django creates fuzzy strings in po files? Why I should remove it? Could you explain?